# Get URL query string and work with it in PHP

Tags: php

I'm not 100% certain where I am messing this up (most likely the check if file exists bit) but what I am trying to do is:

- Get the query of the page e.g. `example.com?example`
- Then use that string to work with the file path (`in this case news/example.php`)
- Then see if that file exists
- Then if it does, include that file, if not echo an error message.

This is the code I have:

```
    $getPage = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $page = "news/"+$getPage+".php";
    if (file_exists($page)) {
    include $page;
    } else {
    echo "The page you are looking for cannot be found. To return back to the main page click <a href='example.com'>here</a>";
    }
```

If the query has to become `example.com?news/example.php` it wouldn't be the end of the world, but the shorter the better; leaving it as just the filename, without the extension, would be better.

Comment: it sounds like you want url rewriting

Comment: Do you want people to be able to go to for example `http://example.com/index.php?p=conctact`, or is that not your question?

Comment: Beware of [RFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability)

Comment: No, essentially the page ```http://example.com``` will be the main page, but when you go to ```http://example.com?ANYTHING``` the content of that page will be whatever page it is including from

Comment: apache redirects everything following the domain name as an absolute file path. If you want URL rewriting, look after .htaccess file.

Comment: @jordsta95 PHP Concatenation does not support `+`, you have to use `.`.

Comment: @Seblor unfortunately we don't have an apache server, it's nginx

Comment: @FrayneKonok YES! That was the issue. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: @jordsta95 I have an answer, you can accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHP Concatenation does not support `+`, you have to use `.`.

```
$getPage = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$page = "news/".$getPage.".php";
if (file_exists($page)) {
    include $page;
} else {
    echo "The page you are looking for cannot be found. To return back to the main page click <a href='example.com'>here</a>";
}
```

Try this, and let me know is it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

In this case URL Rewriting would be much more relevant. 
Create .htaccess file with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([^/\.]+)/?$ news.php?filename=$1 [L]
```

If you are familiar with regex, you'd know that the enclosed brackets `()` are for capturing the match.

`[^/\.]+` is, one or more characters that isn't a forward slash or a period.

After capturing the match, it'll substitute it in the news.php?filename=

So, when you request `http://example.com/news/helloworld` , 
you will be served the `http://example.com/news.php?filename=helloworld`

Now, your news.php file should be like this:

```
$getPage = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$page = "news/".$getPage.".php";
if (file_exists($page)) {
    include $page;
} else {
    echo "The page you are looking for cannot be found. To return back to the main page click <a href='example.com'>here</a>";
}
```

Now you don't have the file extension and the URL looks a lot cleaner.
To read more on URL rewriting, take a look at this: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite